# How to output more than one entity?(oracle sql)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables. MODELS and AUTOMOBILES. And procedure which export all models with name that user inputs and their price(stored in AUTOMOBILES).

```
create or REPLACE procedure modelzz(   VAR_MODEL IN MODELS.NAME_MODEL%TYPE,
                                       VAR_PRICE OUT AUTOMOBILES.A_PRICE%TYPE )
                                       as
                                       begin
SELECT a.A_PRICE
INTO VAR_PRICE
FROM AUTOMOBILES a
join MODELS m
on a.MODELS_ID_MODEL=m.ID_MODEL
where m.NAME_MODEL=VAR_MODEl;
dbms_output.put_line(VAR_MODEL||'''s price is : '||VAR_PRICE);
END;
```

procedure start:

```
var v_modelzz varchar2;
exec modelzz('&model_name',:v_modelzz);
```

The problem is I want to export all entities for certain model. Their's more than one, one model can have two or more records. I know it's not practical. It's just test. Here's the error: `exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`

Answer (score 1):

You should create oracle type (I haven't tested this code, just an example):

```
create type v_price_array
as table of AUTOMOBILES.A_PRICE%TYPE ;
```

change procedure return type to:

```
create or REPLACE procedure modelzz(   VAR_MODEL IN MODELS.NAME_MODEL%TYPE,
                                       VAR_PRICES OUT v_price_array )

Or return created array type from function instead of procedure.
```

And change your select:

```
SELECT a.A_PRICE
BULK COLLECT INTO VAR_PRICES
FROM AUTOMOBILES a
join MODELS m
on a.MODELS_ID_MODEL=m.ID_MODEL
where m.NAME_MODEL=VAR_MODEl;
dbms_output.put_line(VAR_MODEL ||''s price is : '||VAR_PRICE);
```

---

Second way is to return in OUT parameters sys_refcursor. Then you must open cursor inside procedure:

```
create or REPLACE procedure modelzz(   VAR_MODEL IN MODELS.NAME_MODEL%TYPE,
                                       VAR_PRICES OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
                                       as
                                       begin
OPEN VAR_PRICES FOR
SELECT a.A_PRICE
FROM AUTOMOBILES a
join MODELS m
on a.MODELS_ID_MODEL=m.ID_MODEL
where m.NAME_MODEL=VAR_MODEl;
dbms_output.put_line(VAR_MODEL ||''s price is : '||VAR_PRICE);
END;
```

I recomend the second way.